# How to send some commands of Autohotkey automatically, once I run a specific program?

Tags: autohotkey

Hy

- I want to send some commands of Autohotkey automatically once I run a specific program, example:
- when I run ("VMware Workstation") by clicking on its shortcut on the desktop I want to send it some commands automatically after running it.
  what I've tried:

  ```
  #If WinActive("ahk_exe vmware.exe")
  WinWait, VMware Workstation
  CoordMode, Mouse, Window
  ControlClick,x86 y143,VMware Workstation,,Right,1
  Sleep, 2000
  ControlClick,x282 y130 ,VMware Workstation,,Click, 2
  return
  ```

Anybody can help? I'll appreciate it, Thanks advanced.

Comment: Hello, which AHK version? What exactly fails in the script that you tried?

Comment: Why did you edit this to completely simplified question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use in AHK V1 the
[Process command](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/Process.htm)
like this:

```
loop {
    Process, Wait, vmware.exe
    ... do things ...
    Process, WaitClose, vmware.exe
}
```

The above code was not tested by myself with VMware, but should
work according to the documentation.